# How would flow angle change along the length of a propeller airfoil?

Tags: aerodynamics, propeller, blade

Let's assume I have:

- windspeed of 15 m/s
- blade length of 10 m
- rotational speed of one revolution per second

Can someone please help me calculating how the flow angle would change along the length of an airfoil? I have been trying to do the process for the last couple of days but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: A turbine with 10 m blades scribes roughly a 60 meter circle (pi x 2 x 10).  The tips would be going 60 meters per second, the hub, much less.  Holding the 15 m/s wind as constant, you should be able to determine *relative wind* with vector triangles.  Remember to include blade AOA, which is typically less near the tips.

Answer (score 1):

In order to explain the situation, I have drawn a couple of pictures.

Consider a propeller rotating with the rotational velocity $\omega$ (in $\frac{rad}{s}$), which is flying at a velocity of $u$ (in $\frac{m}{s}$).

[image: Propeller with velocities]

(Please excuse my crude drawing skills...). If we cut the propeller at four places along the radius $r$, we get the following velocity triangles (at the respective positions 1, 2, 3 and 4). Note that in the following we look at the propeller from the **tip** in direction of the **hub**:

[image: Speed triangles]

Note that the tangential velocity at each crosssection rises, however the forward velocity stays the same!
The tangential velocity can be simply calculated by the factor $\omega \cdot r$.

Now everything which is left to do is to calculate the angle $\alpha$, which can be simply done by taking the $atan()$ function (btw, I believe that Fern got this point wrong)

$$\alpha = atan(\frac{u}{\omega \cdot r})$$

Therefore in your specific case with $n=1 \frac{rev}{s}$ we get:

$$\alpha = atan(\frac{15}{2\cdot \pi \cdot r})$$

with $r$ going from 0 to 10 meters (in order to remain practical from 0.1 to 10 meters)

Comment: If someone could enlighten me, how to place the pictures centered, that would be great.

Comment: Sorry, no advice about centering pictures besides stuffing them with empty space on the left and then trial and error, but on a propeller the centrifugal forces increase with radius. This lets the slowed-down boundary layer accelerate outwards so it is much harder to achieve flow separation on the outer sections of a propeller than it is on a wing.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \arctan \left( 2 \pi \times n \times \frac{r}{v} \right) $$

- n is the rotational speed in rps
- v is the wind speed in m/s
- r is the radius in m

The relative wind seen by the blade airfoil has 2 components:

- on in the direction of the wind, which value is the actual wind speed $$ v $$
- perpendicular to the wind due to the motion of the blade, which value is the lineal speed of the blade section: $$ \omega \times r$$

So, the angle along the blade will be the one with tangent
$$ \tan  \left( \frac{\omega \times r}{v} \right) $$

Comment: Can you explain ***why*** this is the correct answer? A "magic equation" in isolation doesn't help the OP understand how his problem can be solved, or what the limitations are on this solution.

Comment: actually, I think you mean $atan$ instead of $tan$

Comment: Cotangent instead of tangent...

Comment: atan instead of tan, well, I tried to explain it in the text, but it's true that the redaction can be improved

Comment: contagent instead of tagen, no, it's tangent